# Django 2.0 UpdateView NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django

PLEASE IGNORE!

Trying to use UpdateView to update a model object with name "Tag"

Here is the model:

```
NAME_REGEX = r'^[a-zA-Z0-9\s.\-]+$'

class Tag(TimeStampModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40,
      validators = [
        RegexValidator(regex=NAME_REGEX,
          message='name must be alphanumeric, may contain - _',
          code='invalid tag name')],
      unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=60, unique=True, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        url = reverse('tags:tag_detail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug})
        print('Tag *************** 010 ********************')
        print(url)
        return url

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = make_slug(self.name)
        super().save()
```

I am able to create a Tag using CreateView, list the Tags using ListView and access the Tag detail using DetailView. I am also able to edit the tag using a function based view. However, it falls down with UpdateView.

Here are the urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('tag_list/', views.TagListView.as_view(), name='tag_list'),
    path('tag_detail/<slug:slug>/', views.TagDetailView.as_view(), 
    name='tag_detail'),
    path('create_tag/', views.CreateTagView.as_view(),
    name = 'create_tag'),
    path('update_tag/<slug:slug>/', views.UpdateTagView.as_view(),
    name = 'update_tag'),
    path('category_list/', views.CategoryListView.as_view(),
    name = 'category_list'),
    path('category_detail/<slug>/', views.CategoryDetailView.as_view(),
    name = 'category_detail'),
]
```

In a template called "tag_detail.html" I provide a link that should take the user to an edit form as follows:

```
<p class="slm-red">
  {{ tag_dict.slug }}
  <br>
  <a href="{% url 'tags:update_tag' tag_dict.slug %}">Edit Tag</a>
</p>
```

(I've printed the value of the slug before the link. That is not the problem. The slug value is correct. in this case slug = "brown")

When I click the link it takes me to:

```
http://localhost:8000/tags/update_tag/brown/
```

In this case the slug has the value "brown"

I get the following error message:

```
Reverse for 'update_tag' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['tags\\/update_tag\\/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/$']
```

I tried it the old fashioned way using "url" instead of path and a regular expression for the slug with the same result.

It all works fine when I use a function based view passing slug as a parameter.

Here is the UpdateTagView:

```
class UpdateTagView(UpdateView):
    print('UpdateTagView  **************  010 *****************')
    template_name = 'tags/update_tag.html'
    model = Tag
    fields = ['text']
```

The first line is a print statement. It does not appear on the console log so this confirms that Django never gets as far as the actual view. What I do get on the console log includes the following:

```
[22/Jan/2018 16:06:00] "GET /tags/tag_detail/brown/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4852
Internal Server Error: /tags/update_tag/brown/
```

I've tried several variants but nothing works. I am getting quite desperate.

I've seen similar questions on stack overflow for previous versions of Django but there never seems to be an answer.

When I use an FBV it's simple. I just pass the slug as a parameter along with request.

For what it's worth the errors seems to be occurring in base.py. At the end of the error messages I see:

```
C:\django\_dj\projenv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py in reverse
```

I think there's a kwarg I'm supposed to override but I have no notion how to do it. Since Django never gets as far as the UpdateTagView nothing I do there can affect the outcome.

Comment: Try writing the keyword explicitly: `{% url 'tags:update_tag' slug=tag_dict.slug %}`

Comment: can you add the entire error stack trace

Comment: I found the problem a few minutes after I posted so apologies. In the form tag of my template I had an action that led nowhere! That was the cause of the problem. For the version using the function based view I simply had action="". I feel like an IDIOT.

Comment: @meyerstevenlawrence Well, your question is here, you might as well post your solution and accept it as the answer to give yourself some more reputation points.